# SQL Query find values that have all values of second column

Tags: sql

I have a transactions data table that looks like this:

```
User_ID     Transaction_Type

1000        register
1000        browse
2000        browse
1000        buy
3000        register
```

I need to identify User_ID's that have performed two distinct transaction, e.g. register and buy. How would I be able to do this in SQL?

Comment: Exactly two different, or at least? May one of them also be duplicated?

Comment: Exactly two different, no duplicates would not be seen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select user_id
from transactions t
where transaction_type in ('register', 'buy')
group by user_id
having count(distinct transaction_type) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial if you allow use of a procedural language that pushes the heavy lifting onto the RDBMS with a GROUP BY query, and counts results as they come back from the database.

If you insist on sticking to SQL, then consider this. Think of {register, browse, buy, ...} as ENUMs and assign them distinct bit values, e.g. 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, .... Now bitwise OR them (equivalently find arithmetic sum of distinct values). Create a relation that maps number_of_bits_set to an ordinal, e.g. 0x06 => 2, and JOIN against that table to identify users with the relevant number of distinct transactions.